# [php, maybe regex]how to remove all strings, except [/] + [sequence of 4 or more numbers] (/1111)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a large string stored in a variable (big source code pages), I want everything to be removed, except the 
values that are inside the `href="HERE"`

like this: `href="/45214"`

**it is important that** only values with this format **be preserved:** only one **/** + **numbers, in sequences of 4 or more** numbers

expected output:

/45214

I think it's something like this:
`'/href=\"(\/)[0-9]/'`

```
$source = '</li>
<li >
    <div class="widget-post-holder">

        <a href="/45214" title="care with your skin against 
           pollution" class="post-thumb" >

            <span class="post-cont">
                health            </span>
            <div class="librLoaderLine"></div>
            <img title="care with your skin against pollution"
                 id="0045214"
                 class="te lazy   js-postPreview"
                 data-src="https://wemedic.com/media/posts/201105/23/45214/original/14.jpg"
                 src="https://wemedic.com/media/posts/201105/23/45214/original/14.jpg"
                 data-libr="https://healthandc.com/media/posts/201105/23/45214/libr_225k_45214.webm"
                 alt="care with your skin against pollution" />
            <span class="hd-post" onclick="window.location.href = '/45214'"></span>

        </a>
</li>
<li >
    <div class="widget-post-holder">
        <a href="/7487423" title="natural hair straightening" class="post-thumb" >
            <span class="post-cont">health</span>
            <div class="librLoaderLine"></div>
            <img title="natural hair straightening"
                 id="0045214"
                 class="te lazy   js-postPreview"
                 data-src="https://wemedic.com/media/posts/201105/23/7487423/original/14.jpg"
                 src="https://wemedic.com/media/posts/201105/23/45214/original/14.jpg"
                 data-libr="https://healthandc.com/media/posts/201105/23/7487423/libr_225k_7487423.webm"
                 alt="care with your skin against pollution" />
            <span class="hd-post" onclick="window.location.href = '/7487423'"></span>
        </a>';

preg_match_all("/href=\"(\/)[0-9]/", $source, $results);
var_export(end($results));
```

**expected output:**

```
/45214
/7487423
```

Thanks

Comment: You do not match all digits, use `'~\shref="\K/[0-9]+(?=")~'`. Or `'~\shref="(/[0-9]+)"~'` and then use `$results[1]`.

Comment: To be clear, you don't want to _remove all strings_, you want to match any href attribute with that value within tags.. right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altho' the OP asks for a PHP solution, since it involves HTML, you could also use JavaScript and a regex as follows:

```js
var d = document;
d.g = d.getElementsByTagName;

var aTags = d.g("a");

var matches = [];

var re = /\/\d{4,}/;

for (var i=0, max = aTags.length; i <= max - 1; i++) {
   matches[i] = re.exec(aTags[i].href);
}
  
  
d.body.innerHTML="";
console.log(matches);
```

```html
</li>
    <li >
        <div class="widget-post-holder">

    <a href="/45214" title="care with your skin against 
pollution" class="post-thumb" >

                <span class="post-cont">
                                    health            </span>
                                <div class="librLoaderLine"></div>
                            <img title="care with your skin against pollution"
                     id="0045214"
                     class="te lazy   js-postPreview"
                     data-src="https://wemedic.com/media/posts/201105/23/45214/original/14.jpg"
            src="https://wemedic.com/media/posts/201105/23/45214/original/14.jpg"
                                         data-libr="https://healthandc.com/media/posts/201105/23/45214/libr_225k_45214.webm"
                                      alt="care with your skin against pollution" />
                                <span class="hd-post" onclick="window.location.href ='/45214'"></span>

                                                </a>
                                                </li>
    <li >
        <div class="widget-post-holder">
            <a href="/7487423" title="natural hair straightening" class="post-thumb" >
                <span class="post-cont">
                                    health            </span>
                                <div class="librLoaderLine"></div>
                            <img title="natural hair straightening"
                     id="0045214"
                     class="te lazy   js-postPreview"
                     data-src="https://wemedic.com/media/posts/201105/23/7487423/original/14.jpg"
                   src="https://wemedic.com/media/posts/201105/23/45214/original/14.jpg"
                                         data-libr="https://healthandc.com/media/posts/201105/23/7487423/libr_225k_7487423.webm"
                                      alt="care with your skin against pollution" />
                                <span class="hd-post" onclick="window.location.href ='/7487423'"></span>

                                                </a>
```

Comment: yes, you are right, it is the best practice, best way, your tip is good for everyone, but in this specific project, I am using pure php. Thanks for helping.

Comment: the only thing I needed was the regex, other code here very good(
wiktor super bold code that converted the data to avoid that proceeds of different quotes, but I could not do single outputs to use the wiktor code, which was very different from mine and would change a lot in my code, I'm still with my code + your regex expression), but they were not appropriate for my project, so I continued, I only needed regex: `/\/\d{4,}/` , and only this regex worked in my code, and I used the `array_unique()` to avoid duplicate outputs. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *`DOMDocument`* to extract all `href` attribute values, and then check each with a simple `'~^/\d{4,}$~'` regex that matches

- `^` - start of string
- `/` - a slash
- `\d{4,}` - 4+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

PHP code:

```
$html = "YOUR_HTML_CODE";
$dom   = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = [];
foreach ($xpath->query('//*/@href') as $val) {
    if (preg_match('~^/\d{4,}$~', $val->value)) {
        array_push($results, $val->value);
    }
}
print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /45214
    [1] => /7487423
)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/rrGsp).

Comment: Creating `$html` from a heredoc in the PHP demo is a very nice touch! I was having trouble figuring out how to enclose the source in single quotes when the source itself contains double quotes *and* single quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much @Wiktor Stribiżew. you code helped me a lot :)

Comment: I'm having many duplicate lines in the output, I thought it was easy I solved this by creating a .txt file on the output and doing `$filename = 'postlist.txt';
$text = array_unique(file($filename));

$f = @fopen($filename,'w+');
if ($f) {
  fputs($f, join('',$text));
  fclose($f);
}` but I do not understand why, with your method that does not work! and unfortunately I've never been able to remove duplicate lines in the variable/strings, only in txt file via php ou shell linux, how to do this via string stored in the variable?

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego Do you mean you only want to keep unique values in `$results`? Add a condition: `if (in_array($val->value, $results, TRUE)) { /* add the value */ }`.

Comment: How to write the value !? the value I want is unique, not to repeat values, how to I define in {/ * add the value **HERE ** /} that these values should be unique? I'm used to doing this in strings: `$results = implode(" ",array_unique(explode(" ", $results))); ` For worth informing on your suggestion / solution above, how do I write to be unique it? Thanks

Comment: That is already in the answer. Once you check if the value is missing in the `$results` add it with `array_push($results, $val->value);`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `href=\"(\/)[0-9]{4,}` regex, `{4,}` makes sure to capture 4 or more consecutive numbers.

See example https://regex101.com/r/BlKv9L/1/

```
$re = '/href=\"(\/)[0-9]{4,}/m';
$str = '    <a href="/45214" title="care with your skin against 

    <a href="/452143232" title="care with your skin against 

    <a href="/214" title="care with your skin against 

    <a href="/543543545214" title="care with your skin against 
    <a href="/45215434" title="care with your skin against 
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: `$re = '/\/[0-9]{4,}/'` end + `preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);` + `$array = end($matches);
foreach ($array as $strX) {
  echo $strX = $strX.'<br>';
}` the output was very good. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego if  my answer was good and helped you, please update and accept my answer

Comment: Her response did not help me because she came up with the wrong regex,`/\/\d{4,}/` and you used flags that did not work well in my code: `PREG_SET_ORDER, 0` I just got this regex and add in my code, and I used more `array_unique()`  to fix the duplicate output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[can be checked here](https://regex101.com/r/yZGYoG/1/)

```
<(([^<>"]+"){2})*[^<>"]*href="\K[^"]+
```

Answer (score 0):

***scraper series:***
You can use `preg_match_all()` in an efficient way with a regex that is safe for tag parsing.
*The nice feature of this is that it won't error out if malformed html

and it won't look for it inside invisible content (such as comments, etc...).*

PHP running code

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a182a6d57e887d44f9040166cf57fbb3486bb183

```
<?php
 $string = ' HTML ';

 preg_match_all
    (
        '~(?si)(?:<[\w:]+(?=(?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*?(?<=\s)href\s*=\s*(?:([\'"])\s*(/\d{4,})\s*\1))\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+>\K|<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>".*?"|\'.*?\'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>).*?</\3\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?.*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE.*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[.*?\]\])|(?:--.*?--)|(?:ATTLIST.*?)|(?:ENTITY.*?)|(?:ELEMENT.*?))))>(*SKIP)(?!))~',
        $string,
        $matches,
        PREG_PATTERN_ORDER
    );

print_r( $matches[2] );
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => /45214
    [1] => /7487423
)
```

Regex explained

```
 (?si)                         # Modifier, dot-all and ignore case
 (?:
      # What we want to examine, any tag with href attribute
      < [\w:]+ 
      (?=                        # Assertion (a pseudo atomic group)
           (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
           (?<= \s )
           href \s* = \s*                # href attribute
           (?:
                ( ['"] )                      # (1), # quote begin
                \s* 
                (                             # (2 start)
                     / \d{4,}                      # /dddd (slash, 4 or more digits) to be saved
                )                             # (2 end)
                \s* 
                \1                            # quote end
           )
      )
      \s+ 
      (?: " .*? " | ' .*? ' | [^>]*? )+
      >
      \K                            # Don't store this match, we already have capture group 2 value

   |  
      # OR,
      # Match, but skip these (this just advances the current position)
      <
      (?:
           (?:
                (?:
                     # Invisible content; end tag req'd
                     (                             # (3 start)
                          script
                       |  style
                       |  object
                       |  embed
                       |  applet
                       |  noframes
                       |  noscript
                       |  noembed 
                     )                             # (3 end)
                     (?:
                          \s+ 
                          (?>
                               " .*? "
                            |  ' .*? '
                            |  (?:
                                    (?! /> )
                                    [^>] 
                               )?
                          )+
                     )?
                     \s* >
                )

                .*? </ \3 \s* 
                (?= > )
           )

        |  (?: /? [\w:]+ \s* /? )
        |  (?:
                [\w:]+ 
                \s+ 
                (?:
                     " .*? " 
                  |  ' .*? ' 
                  |  [^>]? 
                )+
                \s* /?
           )
        |  \? .*? \?
        |  (?:
                !
                (?:
                     (?: DOCTYPE .*? )
                  |  (?: \[CDATA\[ .*? \]\] )
                  |  (?: -- .*? -- )
                  |  (?: ATTLIST .*? )
                  |  (?: ENTITY .*? )
                  |  (?: ELEMENT .*? )
                )
           )
      )
      >
      (*SKIP)                      
      (?!)
 )
```